# Discrete Uniform random variable calculate mean and var

Tags: probability, statistics

A lottery player decides to use a random variable generator to help him decide how many tickets to buy. He generates a discrete uniform random variable N taking values 1 through 4 with equal probabilities, and then purchases N lottery tickets. If each of the tickets he buys has (independently of the other tickets) the probability p of winning.

How do you calculate the mean and variance of the number of winning tickets that the player buys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $Z$ is the number of winning tickets, find $E[Z]$ and $E[Z^2]$ by conditioning on the number of tickets he buys.